# Window ignores ShowWindow Minimized the first time, then obeys every time after

Tags: c#, winapi

I have a C# application that I am kicking off a separate win32 window from.  I'm marshaling Win32 api calls into my C# application and trying to control the win32 from that.  I'm toggling the window from a button press to be either maximized on top of all windows always or minimized.

It will show maximized, then ignore the first button press to hide, it then stays showing when I press the button again, then finally hides once I press the button a 3rd time with the same code.  It behaves as desired from here on out.  I'm sure it must be some Windows flags that aren't set properly until it goes through a maximize/minimize cycle first.

Here is the life cycle of the window:

Create window maximized

A:

Hide:

```
target_hwnd = FindWindowHandleByCaption()
ShowWindow(target_hwnd, SW_SHOWMINIMIZED);
```

Show:

```
target_hwnd = FindWindowHandleByCaption()
ShowWindow(target_hwnd, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED);
```

Goto A:

What am I doing wrong?  I've been at this for hours trying various code snippets to no avail.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

Solved my problem by just doing:

```
SendMessage(target_hwnd.ToInt32(), WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MINIMIZE, 0);

SendMessage(target_hwnd.ToInt32(), WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MAXIMIZE, 0);
```

Instead of using ShowWindow.

Comment: You probably try to minimize it too soon, before the app has created the window or called showwindow itself.  Process.WaitForInputIdle() tends to help.  Note that ProcessStartInfo.WindowStyle with the style set to Hidden rarely works, programs do try to avoid trapping the user and forcing them to use Task Manager to terminate the app.  An important malware countermeasure.

Answer (score 2):

Per the [`ShowWindow()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-showwindow) documentation:

> nCmdShow
>   Type: int
>
> Controls how the window is to be shown. **This parameter is ignored the first time an application calls `ShowWindow`, if the program that launched the application provides a `STARTUPINFO` structure**. Otherwise, the first time `ShowWindow` is called, the value should be the value obtained by the `WinMain` function in its `nCmdShow` parameter.
>
> ...
>
> The first time an application calls `ShowWindow`, it should use the `WinMain` function's `nCmdShow` parameter as its `nCmdShow` parameter. Subsequent calls to `ShowWindow` must use one of the values in the given list, instead of the one specified by the `WinMain` function's `nCmdShow` parameter. **As noted in the discussion of the `nCmdShow` parameter, the `nCmdShow` value is ignored in the first call to `ShowWindow` if the program that launched the application specifies startup information in the structure**. In this case, `ShowWindow` uses the information specified in the `STARTUPINFO` structure to show the window. On subsequent calls, the application must call `ShowWindow` with `nCmdShow` set to `SW_SHOWDEFAULT` to use the startup information provided by the program that launched the application. This behavior is designed for the following situations:
>
> - Applications create their main window by calling `CreateWindow` with the `WS_VISIBLE` flag set.
> - Applications create their main window by calling `CreateWindow` with the `WS_VISIBLE` flag cleared, and later call `ShowWindow` with the `SW_SHOW` flag set to make it visible.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification but how do I fix my problem?  I can't seem to call ShowWindow twice in one frame to make it change.